# how to change authors tag of the below xml file using apache camel using spring boot

Tags: apache-camel

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

how can i change the author tag of above xml file using apache camel with spring boot

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: If you are planning to use Apache Camel with Spring Boot. Please keep in mind of a lot of gotchas and complexity of running another framework into another.

You have to consider how you are receiving the request above, then you can simply leverage on [JacksonXML](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/jacksonxml-dataformat.html) dependency to handle the unmarshalling for you, and proceed to update the payload in a deserialised/POJO format.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XSLT. Create your own template file for transformation.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/xslt-component.html

You can use it in Spring Boot too.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-xslt-starter</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```